# How to upgrade Xiaomi Redmi 3 to Android Marshmallow?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, xiaomi

I have recently updated the MIUI 7 to MIUI 8. Thought it was based on Android Marshmallow. But it is on the same Lollipop version. How do I update it into Marshmallow? I know there is no official way to upgrade. So looking for other ways.

Comment: Redmi 3/Prime latest update is Lollipop 5.1. You can check updates using Tools-> Updater.

Answer (score 1):

As of now MIUI 8 is still Lollipop (and will likely stay that way due to Xiaomi pushing Redmi 4 series), and there's no Marshmallow-based port either, so you will have to make a choice between up-to-date Android version and MIUI UI/features.

If you do decide that living on the cutting edge is worth the sacrifice, start [unlocking](http://en.miui.com/unlock/) and flashing custom ROMs. [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-3) will give you a good start, hosting a number of popular ROMs such as [LineageOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-3/development/rom-cyanogenmod-14-0-t3481701) (this would even bump you to Nougat).